# SQL - PHP Multiple Set

Tags: php, sql, web

im busy trying to set multiple fields in my DB and it is not working for some reason. Can you take a look and let me know where i have gone wrong? Thank you

```
<?php
error_reporting('E_ALL');
include 'db_header.php';

$id = $_GET['ID'];
$bronzeTokens = $_GET['bronzeTokens'];
$silverTokens = $_GET['silverTokens'];
$goldTokens = $_GET['goldTokens'];
$platinumTokens = $_GET['platinumTokens'];

$sql = "UPDATE Player SET bronzeTokens = $bronzeTokens, goldTokens = $goldTokens, silverTokens = $silverTokens, platinumTokens = $platinumTokens WHERE ID = $id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: What datatype are these fields? If they're strings, you need to put the values in quotes. But it would be best if you use parametrized queries.

Comment: They are ints, the reason i know its not working as the DB is not updating. I can echo out the values which is good i know they are updated, but the DB is not updating?

Comment: Strongly recommend you use a [parameterized query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) to avoid SQL injection attacks. You should probably also check for error codes to see if a query succeeded or failed (and why).

Comment: Ok was me being totally stupid, i forgot to set the id

Comment: @rutter & burmerThanks guys gonna check these out, i heard of them but never looked into them! Thanks!